# Can Intel QuickSync video create interleaved H.264 video with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, encoding

In ffmpeg, rather than using `libx264` I'd like to use the Intel QuickSync accelerated encoder to encode to H.264 interlaced video.

I can't find any documentation which says if the quicksync encoder supports interlace or not.

For "normal" encoding with QuickSync I'd use something like

```
ffmpeg -y -hwaccel qsv \
  -hwaccel_output_format vaapi -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128  \
  -i inputFile.mp4 \
  -c:v h264_qsv outputFile.mp4
```

But the output is progressive. Is there a way, using `h264_qsv` to create interlaced output?

Comment: Share full log.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the source is progressive too?

It should be possible to interlace it with the interlace filter:
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#interlace

But I don't know if there is a possibility to do this in hardware, so you may have to do interlacing in software, and then pass it to the hardware encoder and see if you get interlaced output...

(What do you need interlaced video for anyway?! ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that (and provide full logs to @Gyan).  Hardware is unavailable at the moment.  Interlace video still used for many commercial television broadcasts...

Comment: I can't test it with qsv, but my first try would probably be adding (after **-i ...**)